# How can I make a flex child element shrink (hide) in and out smoothly?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a flex container that has the child element animate to shrink and grow while having the remaining child elements grow to fill in the space.

The not perfect, but close way I found is to set the `max-width` to `0px` and the borders' widths to `0px`. However, to get this to work I need to set the initial `max-width`. If I set it to `100%` when **I get a delay when the transition starts**. I think it's because the initial max-width is 100 and it's going down to 0 and most of that is not seen. I can make it more responsive if I set the `max-width` closer to the child sizes, but if I want to shrink and grow another child I get the same issue.

How can I smoothly transition child elements to grow and shrink, without any delays and have the growing elements and shrinking elements transition at the same time?

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/Adrian-contreras-Tb/pen/YzMQNXp

```css
.flex_parent {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  gap: 3px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex_parent:hover #_1 {
  transform: scale(0);
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-width: 0px;
  border-width: 0px;
}

.child {
  background-color: purple;
  border: 3px solid silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 80px;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_parent">
  <div class="child" id="_1">test</div>
  <div class="child" id="_2">test</div>
  <div class="child" id="_3">test</div>
  <div class="child" id="_4">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not need max-width, the flex properties should do the job.

Do not forget that even scaled to zero , your text is still there and need space. overflow:hidden on this element will avoid the text be there taking room.

example below

***edit** you can also swallow the gap with a negative margin if needed.*
*also, put your updated rules behind common rules to avoid them to be overwritten* ;)

```css
.flex_parent {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  gap: 3px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.child {
  background-color: purple;
  border: 3px solid silver;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  flex-basis: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  flex-grow: 1;
  transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.flex_parent:hover #_1 {
  transform: scale(0);
  padding: 0px;
  /*margin: 0px;*/
  margin-left:-3px;/* pulls the gap aside it */
  flex:0 1 0;
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_parent">
  <div class="child" id="_1">test</div>
  <div class="child" id="_2">test</div>
  <div class="child" id="_3">test</div>
  <div class="child" id="_4">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `overflow: auto;` to `.child` will make the 'out' animation even smoother.

Comment: @TechySharnav i do not see much difference aside that overflow should be set by defaut on .child instead .flex_parent:hover #_1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add `flex-grow: 0;` in your child element , and your animations be smoother
https://jsfiddle.net/0rx6w43t/18/

```
.flex_parent:hover #_1 {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```